# R: Extract numbers after a specific string

Tags: r, string

I have a pretty messy vector like this:

```
purchase <- c('group1apple:45pear:50peach32apple15','group2peach25banana34apple15orange35','group3grape300peach42apple54pear35')
```

and I want extract the number after all `apple:`, which means I wang to get a output like:

`apple <- c(45,15,15,54)`

I tried`str_extract(purchase, "(?i)(?<=apple:\\D)\\d+")`
but not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
> unlist(str_extract_all(purchase, 'apple:?(\\d+)')) %>% str_extract_all('\\d+') %>% unlist() %>% as.numeric()
[1] 45 15 15 54
```

Or using Positive Look Behind:

```
> as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(purchase, '(?<=apple:?)\\d+')))
[1] 45 15 15 54
>
```

Comment: Thx! that works for most of the data, but it can only get first 2 digits of the number. with 'apple:345' in some group with 3 digits or more, it still only get first 2 digits.

Comment: OK, from your data shared I assumed it'd be 2 digits, I have made the change now, can you please check.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always `apple:` (which is not true in your example), then you could do:

```
str_extract(purchase, "(?<=apple:)[0-9]*")
```

Comment: with ```str_extract(purchase, "(?<=apple:)[0-9]*")``` I can only get
[1] "45" NA   NA

Comment: @richardzhang you said you want to extract everything after `apple:` but only your first string in your example contains `apple:`, all the others are just `apple`

Answer (score 1):

So, in your example, not every number is exactly following the string `apple:`.  Some of them are following `apple` which is different.

Also, `str_extract_all` is the one you want, not `str_extract`.

```
str_extract_all(purchase, "(?<=apple:?)\\d+") %>% unlist() %>% as.numeric()
```

**Edit:** I recommend you check out this link: https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Find the **Work with Strings Cheatsheet** there and keep it with you always.